# Multisim simulation of AVR fusebit doctor

Tags: avr, simulation, multisim, fuse-bits

I've found a very interesting fusebit doctor. This is a tool to repair the fuses of ATtinys.

Link: http://mdiy.pl/attiny-fusebit-hvsp-doctor/?lang=en

This is the original schematic: 
[image]

I want to replace the +12V power circuit for a +5V power circuit.

First of all, I've simulated the +12V circuit:
[image]

And I don't why, I'm getting +4V, instead of +12V.

These AVR's are repaired with +12V in its reset pin.

Does anyone know why I'm not getting +12V ?

Comment: Uhh is your 12v battery the right way around?

Comment: Your 12V battery (V1) is connected backward.

Comment: That is not the problem, I've tried to connected backwards, and the multimeter shows 22nV

Comment: It's certainly *a* problem, although there are other problems in your circuit. I notice that your multimeter is connected backwards, and the voltage is actually -4V, because the battery is backwards. It looks like S1 is turned off, should it be turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, your battery is definitely backwards, and your multimeter XMM1 is as well. the switches in your switch S1 look like they are not in the proper positions. One should be up, and one should be down. They should never be both up or down.

What should happen is that if the right one is on and the left one off, you should read ~0V. If the left one is on and the right is off, you should read 12V. You'll have to experiment to see which way round the switch goes (up=off or on)

Comment: you're right. What do you recommend me to do to get 12V from 5V ?

Comment: There are a few ways, but by far the easiest is to just put a 9v and two 1.5V batteries in series. You could look up "boost converters" and "voltage doublers".